# HTML Agility Pack RemoveChild - not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Say I want to remove the span tag from this html:

```
<html><span>we do like <b>bold</b> stuff</span></html>
```

I'm expecting this chunk of code to do what I'm after

```
string html = "<html><span>we do like <b>bold</b> stuff</span></html>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

HtmlNode span = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span").First();
span.ParentNode.RemoveChild(span, true); //second parameter is 'keepGrandChildren'
```

But the output looks like this:

```
<html> stuff<b>bold</b>we do like </html>
```

It appears to be reversing the child nodes within the span.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a bug in HtmlAgilityPack - see their issue register:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/9113

Interestingly this was raised 4 years ago...

Here's a snippet that will remove all span tags (or any other tag you specify) and keeps other nodes in the correct order.

```
void Main()
{
    string html = "<html><span>we do like <b>bold</b> stuff</span></html>";
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    RemoveTags(doc, "span");
    Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
}

public static void RemoveTags(HtmlDocument html, string tagName)
{
    var tags = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//" + tagName);
    if (tags!=null)
    {
        foreach (var tag in tags)
        {
            if (!tag.HasChildNodes)
            {
                tag.ParentNode.RemoveChild(tag);
                continue;
            }

            for (var i = tag.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var child = tag.ChildNodes[i];
                tag.ParentNode.InsertAfter(child, tag);
            }
            tag.ParentNode.RemoveChild(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly this is still happening in 2017

Comment: ...and in 2019. Thanks for the excellent suggestion and code. Works great!

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (HtmlNode child in tag.ChildNodes)
{
    tag.ParentNode.InsertBefore(child, tag);
}

tag.Remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the records, this is my version, based on the answers of this question:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

internal static class HtmlAgilityPackExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveNodeKeepChildren(this HtmlNode node)
    {
        foreach (var child in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            node.ParentNode.InsertBefore(child, node);
        }
        node.Remove();
    }
}
```